# sweetalert ajax functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

i am trying to use sweetAlert2 for my ajax, creating a form inside and then do its process and get the results back, but i am stuck at one point which is when i send the results how do i process the ajax inside it,

Here is my code as of now

```
Swal.fire({
            title: 'Request PlayForm',
            html: `<textarea name="da" id="da"></textarea>`,
            confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
            focusConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: () => {
                const textData = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#da').value
                if (da== '') {
                Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please enter details.`)
                }
                return { da: da}
            }
            }).then((result) => {
            Swal.fire(`
                Email Sent Successfully -- this message should come when i get a success from my ajax else it will display error which i can get from ajax 
            `.trim())
        })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Request PlayForm',
  html: `<textarea name="da" id="da"></textarea>`,
  confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
  focusConfirm: false,
  preConfirm: () => {
      const textData = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#da').value;
      if(!textData || !textData.trim()) {
          Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please enter details.`)
      }
      return textData;
  }
}).then((result) => {
    var myResult = result.value;
    console.log("calling ajax");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + myResult,
      //data: {'da':myResult}, <== use this if you're sending any data
      type: 'get', // or post, depending what you do in the background,
      // dataType: 'json' - data type of your response. It's optional,
      // you can set it to something else, like text, or application/pdf,
      //or something else
      beforeSend: function() {
        console.log("this is before send - we want to get some info " + myResult);
        // disable buttons to prevent double clicks,
        // or do something else
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // Process the response - data
        // Send mail if successful
        if(data) {
          Swal.fire(`
            Email Sent Successfully -- this message should come
            when i get a success from my ajax else it will display
            error which i can get from ajax 
            `.trim());
            console.log(data);
        } else {
          Swal.fire(`There was an error: ` /* your error here*/);
        }
      },
      error: function(desc, err) {
        Swal.fire(`
           AJAX error! Description: ` + JSON.stringify(desc) + `,
           error: ` + JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    });
    // END AJAX
});
// END .then(...)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

The variable `myResult` (you can name it whatever you like) stores the result of `da` / return of your `preconfirm`. You could process it later on, to see if it matches what you expect (for example, whether there were any illegal characters, or if you were expecting a number, or a certain format, but the user decided to be cheeky and type in something else, etc).

If the input was alright, you move on to the `else` part in the `.then(...)`, and call your AJAX there. Read the comments in the code for more info.

Comment: does not properly, da does not seems to be going right `const textData = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#da').value
      if (da== '') {
          Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please enter details.`)
      }
      return { da: da}`

Comment: You're right - my code had errors. I've updated the answer, and added a snippet for testing. Your original code wasn't passing the validation because of the way you were testing. See the updated code for validation which works.